# export to CSV from MONGODB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

i have a **CUSTOMER** collection in my Mongo database , the collection has a sub document  which is an array of bookings , means this array show all the bookings of user and the data in this array is in form of objects e.g at Object0 {REQUESTID:data , STATUS:data , DETAILS:data } etc .. I have converted this collection into CSV file , the problem is that in CSV file in **BOOKING COLUMN** it does not show my proper array data but it show **[OBJECT0,OBJECT1,...]** etc . is there any way to change this , means when i convert this collection into CSV it must show proper data same as it shows in MONGODB ... 
here is my code

```
app.get('/exporttocsv', function (req, res, next) {
    var filename = "MechanicApp.csv"
    Customer.find().lean().exec({}, function (err, products) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
        res.csv(products, true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please share the sample data of `products` returned by your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your task easier you can use npm package [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv)

Or [json-2-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-2-csv)

Comment: thanks mate :) .. one more thing , considering the above code if i want to skip specific column while exporting to CSV how can i do that .. forexample i want to skip name column from collection when it converts into CSV

Comment: You have to remove that key `name` from your json just right before exporting to `csv`

Comment: thanks a lot , if possible can you provide me with code . i would really appreciate that

Comment: You can check here https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv#example-3 . At this link they are telling an option through which you can choose that which columns you want to export